# Packaging javascript and css files in a django app for reuse, install via pip?

Tags: javascript, python, django, pip

I'm building a django app that requires a javascript file for some ajaxy bits.  I would like to package this app so that it can be installed by via easy_install or pip with as little fuss as possible.

But I'm not sure what where to put the static media, particularly the javascript file.  On my machine, I have the static media in an external directory, not served by django.  All the internal references in my template point to MEDIA_URL.

Is there a standard for where to package/include/attach static media for reusable django apps?  Is there a way to package the app so that others can just use it without messing with moving all the javascript/css files, or some way to automate that during the install process?

I'm using django 1.2 -- haven't upgraded the server to 1.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [`staticfiles` app](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) is exactly what you're looking for, unfortunately it's new in Django 1.3. Are you able to upgrade?

From the docs:

> `django.contrib.staticfiles` collects static files from each of your applications (and any other places you specify) into a single location that can easily be served in production.

**EDIT:** As per Wogan's comment, if you don't want to upgrade to 1.3 then you can use the [Staticfiles standalone app](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-staticfiles/). It's what Django's built in staticfiles app was originally derived from.

Comment: Even if you don't want to use django 1.3, you can still use staticfiles as a standalone app. See http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-staticfiles/

Comment: Nope, I can't upgrade to 1.3, but if I can pull it in as a standalone app, we should be good to go!